# Excel Single Use Dropdownlist

Tags: excel, vba, list, if-statement, drop-down-menu

My problem is the following.
I have two tables.
The first table is a guest list where the information on who is the guest and how many beds he need is stored. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aiNA.png)
And the second table contains the Apartment names and the number of provided beds.
Now I want to make a dropdown list in the guest list table where only Beds are shown that provide the right amount of beds. And after a Apartment is selected it cant be picked a second time.
Can someone provide me a code for this solution?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you ([No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)). Reading [Ask] might help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is functionality in Excel to use Dropdowns, to do this you need to identify your drop down requirements as shown below. Only include items the dropdown list if these not going to change.

I recommend to create a new tab in your excel workbook for list, then you can reference this in cell you want -https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/video-create-and-manage-drop-down-lists-28db87b6-725f-49d7-9b29-ab4bc56cefc2

**Dropdown list**

Guest 1

Guest 2

Guest 3

**Assumptions:**

Sound like you need know if bed a is available based off guest drop down list. If bed is available or not it can't be selected again.
I will let you attempt this but you can try and use **IF Statement or VLOOKUP.**

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! 
I already figured out the part with the dropdown list. (That was easy)
The thing I cant figure out is how I can remove an Apartment from the list if it already has been allocated to a guest.